# Swift Optional values out of an NSSet

Tags: swift, nsset, optional-values

Self.vertices is an NSSet. I'm having trouble getting the Vertex value out of the optional

The code below crashes in playgrounds.

```
func getVertex (x: Double, y: Double,z: Double) -> Vertex?
{

    for v : Vertex! in self.vertices {

        if v.isEqualTo(x, y: y, z: z) {
            return v
        }
    }
    return nil

}
```

Comment: Please post your full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that may be helpful:

```
let set: NSSet = // ...

for object : AnyObject in set {
    if let vertex = object as? Vertex {
        // do the main course
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe self.vertices contains AnyObject. So you should use following code

```
func getVertex (x: Double, y: Double,z: Double) -> Vertex?
{
    for v : AnyObject in self.vertices {
       if v is Vertex {
           if v.isEqualTo(x, y: y, z: z) {
              return v
           }
       }
    }
    return nil
}
```